# how to create a vector of int 2D array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array

i am trying to create a vector of int 2D array in c++
but my following code has some errors that i can't realize why?!

```
vector< int[2][2] > vec;
int a[2][2];
vec.push_back(a);
```

i don't want to use int ** int my vetor (and create a 2D array using new)

and i know each of 2D arrays has just 2 col and row (the size is static)

so is there any way to implement that vector or not?

and i also try to push_back just an array to vecotr and it wasn't successful too! why?

```
vector< int[2] > vec;
int a[2];
vec.push_back(a);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell us what error you are getting?

Comment: This has been asked so many times! But choice of container might differ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Native arrays are not copyable, moveable or assignable, so they cannot be stored in a standard container.

However, the wrapper `std::array<T,N>` is, so `std::vector<std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> >` is one way to do what you want.

Comment: I'd be very grateful if you could explain why using std:array<T,N> is a rubbish way to do things. I would just use new myself and not bother with native arrays, but still, I'm curious.

Comment: @batbrat: Well, I was being a little dramatic there, but it's a lot of nesting for a single type. I'd be more inclined to make a class `MyNewClass` that derives `std::array<int, 4>` and implements 2D-indexing on top of it, so that you end up with a simple `std::vector<MyNewClass>`... though many people will tell you that this is over-engineering. Including, actually, me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2D vector in this way: `std::vector <std::vector <data_type> > vector_name`

**Note:** In C++03, there must be a white space between `>` and `>`.

Comment: space is required in C++03, not in C++11.

Comment: In C++11 it is no longer required for there to be a space between > and >

Comment: @YoungJohn and Jarod42 Thanks for letting me know. I am not much aware of C++11 feature. Will look soon.